# Pointer to double initialization

Tags: c, pointers

I'm certain that I'm missing something basic here, trying to figure out why I'm getting the following output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  double val1 = 20.0;
  double *p1;
  p1 = &val1;

  printf("p1 is %f\n", p1);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
p1 is 0.000000
```

However, if I print the value of val1 before p1, it seems to be assigned to the correct value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  double val1 = 20.0;
  double *p1;
  p1 = &val1;

  printf("val1 is %f\n", val1);
  printf("p1 is %f\n", p1);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
val1 is 20.000000 
p1 is 20.000000
```

Comment: The lesson here is to enable and read compiler warnings. `gcc -Wall file.c` would answer your question.

Comment: It's possible I wasn't entirely clear in my question - I understand/expect why the first case printed as it did.  I'm really curious as to why the second case printed out the value using the same code - I would expect it to print val1 as 20 and p1 as 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are passing to `printf` the pointer to double, not the double:

```
printf("p1 is %f\n", *p1);
```

That should do it!

Note 1: Beware! passing the wrong type to `printf` (in this case, a `double*` instead of a `double` will cause *Undefined Behavior*.

Note 2: Arguments to variadic functions, such as `printf` will suffer arithmetic promotions, so `float` values will be passed as `double`, `short` and `char` as `int`, and so on. So you can pass `float` and `double` for a `%f` format specification without trouble.

Note 3: But beware! `float*` will not be promoted to `double*`, because it is not an arithmetic type (it is a pointer). That's why the `*scanf()` family of functions has much more format specifiers than the `*printf`: because the former take pointers and the latter values.

Comment: You are correct that causes the initial case to print out the 20.00 as expected - however, I'm still curious as to why the second case works if I print the pointed-to value ahead of time?

Comment: @apusateri: As I said before, it is _Undefined Behavior_, so anything can happen. In your particular case, you are probably in a 32-bit little-endian system (i386?), so `sizeof(double)==8` and `sizeof(double*)==4`. When you do the first call, the correct value is copied in the stack: 8 bytes. Then the second call will overwrite the first 4 bytes, but leave the last 4 bytes untouched. As it happened, the last 4 bytes probable are the most significant, so you get more or less the same value...

Comment: Thanks! This is more or less what I was hoping to discover - figured it would be something implementation specific, but was still curious.

Comment: @apusateri: Beware! (I think I'm abusing this word ;-) This is not _Implementation Specific_, it is _Undefined Behavior_. It happened that in your particular runs, in your particular machine and OS, it behave this way, but never rely on UB, because sooner or later it will behave differently.

Comment: @apusateri: Note that most modern compilers will warn about wrong uses of `printf()`. Just enable the right warning level. For example in GCC use `-Wall`.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("p1 is %f\n", *p1);
                     ^
```

Answer (score 1):

To refer to the value at the memory location pointed to by the pointer, you need to de-reference it.

`double *p;`

The value is then obtained by `*p` and not `p` alone.
Remember that `p` is merely the pointer.

For your example:
`printf('p1 is %f\n",*p1)`